# Saber a quantia de números para qual um ponteiro aponta

Tags: c, array, lógica

minha dúvida é se existe uma forma algébrica simples de determinar a quantia de números para qual um ponteiro aponta.
Por exemplo:

```
int vet_inteiro[] = {...};
int tam_vetor = (int) sizeof(vet_inteiros)/sizeof(int); // aqui eu tenho o tamanho do vetor
```

Mas e se eu quisesse a quantia de numeros para qual um ponteiro aponta.

```
int* ptr_int = calloc(numero, sizeof(int));

// eu sei explicitamente que numero é a quantia de numeros para qual o ponteiro aponta mas
// mas haveria alguma forma de fazer isso da forma :: tam_pont = sizeof(ptr_int)/sizeof(int)
// eu sei de antemão que não da certo porque sizeof(ptr_int) é o tamanho do ponteiro
```

Comment: eu não entendi bem o que quer com "a quantidade de números". Imagina um array assim: `int vet_inteiro[] = {1, 2, 3}` o tamanho desse array é 3, e quantidade de números (pode ser chars ou strings dependendo do tipo do array) também é 3 ou tem outro conceito para "quantidade de números" ou "quantidade de elementos" no array ?

Comment: @RicardoPontual é exatamente isso, mas queria saber se há alguma forma de determinar isso a parti de um ponteiro, saber para quantos locais de memoria de inteiro ele aponta.

Comment: ainda não tendi... no exemplo acima a quantidade de locais que aponta são 3, por exemplo `vet_inteiro[0]` aponta para a primeira posição de memória, onde está o valor `1`, ainda não consigo entender, para mim o tamanho (sizeof) e quantidade de locais de memória é a mesma coisa

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal, eu estava tentando conseguir a quantia de endereços de inteiros para quais o ponteiro aponta sem tem conhecimento desse número usado no calloc. Não entendi bem o que procuro, vou fechar a pergunta, obrigado pela ajuda vou tentar reformular.